# Learning Joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I am thinking of starting to learn Joomla 1.7 but don't know where to begin.

I am interested in learning to create blogs, e-commerce websites, forums and other type of websites. I know that there is probably a lot of learning involved but I am willing to commit.

I should also mention that my knowledge starts at XHTML\CSS and ends in Javascript\jQuery (and a bit of Java up to Swing), however I have never done any PHP/MySql programming.

Do I need to learn PHP and MySql before learning Joomla or I can start learning it now?

If I don't need to learn PHP and MySql first what book/tutorial/video tutorial would you recommend for someone who never used a CMS before and would like to learn it to its full extent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second the recommendation of the official documentation. http://docs.joomla.org/ overall a fantastic resource, although the wiki format can make navigation tricky. I recommend looking for and clicking the 'Category' links under any article - and/or clicking the back button when you've finished reading a page to go back to the category listing.

For free documentation I'd recommend Hagen Graf's 'books' available as free downloads from:

Here for the Joomla 1.6 version:
http://cocoate.com/joomla-16-english

Here for the Joomla 1.7 version
http://cocoate.com/2011/07/joomla-17-beginners-guide

There are other useful websites for learning to use Joomla:

http://www.compassdesigns.net/

http://www.alledia.com/

http://www.joomlablogger.com/

http://brian.teeman.net/

I've included the 1.6 documentation for anyone out there who is using that particular version, but there is no reason to stick with 1.6 as it is no longer supported.

Presentations by Jen Kramer: http://www.slideshare.net/jen4web

Presentations but Brian Teeman: http://www.slideshare.net/brianteeman

There are many other useful resources too - I'll probably return to this post and add some more resources later.

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation is pretty good so I suggest your starting point should be [here](http://docs.joomla.org/). As the documentation also suggests you should install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) in order to run a local Joomla site for experimentation. XAMPP will get out of the way installing/configuring httpd, setting up PHP and MySQL.

I've put several Joomla sites together and I can guarantee you don't need to know PHP/MySQL to put something good together.

Comment: I already installed joomla on my computer by using WAMP now I need some strong documentation from top to bottom to olearn to work with it well.

Comment: I've learned everything I needed from the official doc and then google my way for any questions I had along the journey.